# Bootstrap col's aren't organized nicely

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi dear smarter folks,

I hope you can help me out with a perhaps simple problem in Bootstrap. See the website attached:

http://www.marciplan.com/prt-2/

Why don't the articles (the blank pages) fit under each other nicely? I want them to look like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgZos.jpg)
I hope someone wants to put in the effort to help this dummy out. Thanks a bunch :)

Kind regards,
Marciplan

Answer (score 0):

That's because the height of the second article is greater than the other two articles on the top row. The way to fix this set a fixed height for the each articles(say 400px would suit the best).

But on smaller devices you may need to use media queries to adjust the height.

**EDIT:**
Try this for pinterest like grids
[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but having a fixed height would ruin the idea. I want the articles to be like Pinterest has with their stuff. If it's all perfectly organized it kinda looks meh :(

Answer (score 0):

You firstly need to add a clearfix class to `<div id="content">` as its floated children are collapsing its height: `<div id="content" class="clearfix">`.

Try adding the following to the #content CSS selector:

```
#content {
   display: flex;
}
```

That seemed to fix it for me. I would wrap it in a media query so that normal stacking behavior when the browser is resized or viewed on a smaller device isn't affected:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #content {
       display: flex;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Further to your comment, you should also add the `flex-wrap: wrap;` property to the wrapping `<div id="content" class="clearfix">`... By default, flexbox tends to try and fit children on the same line:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #content {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Flex seemed to work. But when I put flex there it'll display 4 rows instead of 3. (Which is weird because they are col-md-4's).. What might I do about that? (It's on the site now)